# Enum with attributes and performance

Tags: c#, .net

I plan to use enum with attributes instead of lookup tables. I worry about performance. Should I query attributes once and create static dictionary for example? Are there out of box solutions?

Comment: Why do you think you're going to have a performance problem? Have you tried the code? I would wait to start over-complicating things until you know you have a real need to optimize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should worry about performance when you have a slow application, not before.

Make sure you application works and works correctly, before you start optimizing it.

The right way to deal with performance is to measure and find bottle necks using a performance monitor, then fixing the worst cases.

You question and approach describes micro-premature-optimization at its worst.

Answer (score 1):

This question is difficult to answer because you haven't provided any details about the expected frequency of calls. You might expect a performance penalty from using Reflection to query attributes but is this penalty going to be bottleneck to your application? The only way to know is to perform load tests. I am afraid that at this stage you are doing what is called premature optimization.